# Exclude assigned objects from edit form one to one relationship in django admin forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models named `RecId` and `Record` in OneToOne relationship,

**models.py**

```
class RecId(models.Model):
    rec_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rec_id)


class Record(models.Model):
    rec_id = models.OneToOneField(RecId, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rec_id)
```

My problem is,

In default, django admin **Record edit form** edit field (RecId field) shows all the `rec_ids` in `RecId` table. But I need to show only records that can be assigned to a **Record** (because the relationship between two tables is OneToOne, one id can only be assigned to one record)

I tried to do that by using `formfield_for_foreignkey()` method but currently stuck with the query

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Record)
class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['rec_id', 'desc', 'user']
    search_fields = ['rec_id', 'user']

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "rec_id":
            kwargs["queryset"] = RecId.objects.all().exclude(... The query ...)
        return super(RecordAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I tried to query it by using `~Exists(Record.objects.filter(rec_id__eq=OuterRef('pk')))` an hour or two ago and it didn't work. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured it out :)
The query should be `RecId.objects.filter(record__isnull=True)` so the **admin.py** would looks like,

```
@admin.register(Record)
class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['rec_id', 'desc', 'user']
    search_fields = ['rec_id', 'user']

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "rec_id":
            kwargs["queryset"] = RecId.objects.all().exclude(
                                      RecId.objects.filter(record__isnull=True)
                                      )
        return super(RecordAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```